# How to match a string in double quotes with escaping?

Tags: .net, json, regex, string

I'm pretty sure, that I can't do that with a regex, but maybe one of you knows it better.
This is my pattern so far:

```
^\[\s*"[^\n]+?(?<!\\)"(?:,\s*"[^\n]+?(?<!\\)")*\s*\]
```

(it's in .NET syntax, `(?:)` is a non capturing group,
`(?<!)` a negative look behind group)
It's for a json string array, so I have to care for escaped double quotes here.
`(?<!\\)"`
My problem is, that my pattern matches these example strings:

```
["", ""]
```

and also

```
["1"", "2"]
```

I know why:
`[^\n]+?` has a trailing non greedy sign, but it catches unescaped closing double quotes to match `"[^\n]+?(?<!\\)"` in the first example and another group `,\s*"[^\n]+?(?<!\\)"` in the second example string.

**What I would need is a regex to always stop at the very first closing unescaped double quotes, regardless what is coming next.**

So I think it's too ambiguous for regex.

Comment: I wrote a json parser for my problem a week ago yet, so this is really only a regex question...

Comment: BTW/FYI: I've tried the newtonsoft.json module for PowerShell as a json deserializer and 50% of the error messages were useless and without a location info, so I wrote my own with always detailed error messages and the correct error line number.

Comment: FYI Json.NET is the most popular Json parser, used in ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Web API. And yes, the line numbers are correct if the *lines* are correct. If there's only one line, or if there's one JSON fragment per line it may be harder to find what's wrong. If you have parsing problems ask about them. Don't assume the most popular NuGet package is broken

Comment: @
PanagiotisKanavos
 you've made your point, clearly the OP wants a regex solution, all you can do is give your advice and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably do it

`(?s)^\[\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(?:\s*,\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")*\s*\]`

https://regex101.com/r/mT66Nd/1

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-all modifier
 ^                             # BOS
 \[                            # Open [
 \s*                           # optional wsp

 "                             # Open dbl quote
 [^"\\]*                       # optional not dbl quote nor escape
 (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*           # optional escape anything, not dlb quote nor escape
 "                             # Close dbl quote

 (?:                           # Cluster
      \s* ,  \s*                    # opt wsp, comma, opt wsp
      "                             # Same as above
      [^"\\]*                        
      (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
      "                             
 )*                            # End cluster, do 0 to many times
 \s*                           # optional wsp
 \]                            # Close ]
```

Comment: so great and easy, thanks.I've just added 2x `(?!")` since I don't want to allow empty strings here. So the final regex I'll use is: `(?s)^\[\s*"(?!")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"(?:\s*,\s*"(?!")[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*")*\s*\]`

Comment: I had to correct this pattern at little, since it allowed newlines in mid string, which is invalid in json. The final pattern now is: `^\[\s*"(?!")[^"\\\n]*(?:\\[^\n][^"\\\n]*)*"(?:\s*,\s*"(?!")[^"\\\n]*(?:\\[^\n][^"\\\n]*)*")*\s*\]`